Generation of a Voronoi noise normal map using the analytic derivative method
I'm working on a personal moon generation project using Voronoi noise, slightly modified for crater generation.
Here's the code:
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

float random(vec2 st) {
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy,vec2(12.9898,78.233)))*43758.5453123);
}

vec2 random2(vec2 p) {
    return fract(sin(vec2(dot(p,vec2(127.1,311.7)),dot(p,vec2(269.5,183.3))))*43758.5453);
}

float smoothMin(float a, float b, float k) {
    float h = max(k - abs(a- b), 0.0) / k;
    return min(a, b) - h * h * k * (1.0 / 4.0);
}

float smoothMax(float a, float b, float k) {
    float h = max(k - abs(a - b), 0.0) / k;
    return max(a, b) + h * h * k * (1./4.);
}

const float scale = 2.0;
const float rimWidth = 0.188;
const float rimSteepness = 0.5;
const float floorHeight = -2.524;
const float smoothness = 0.344;

float cratersFractal(vec2 st) {
    float height = 0.5;
    float amplitude = 1.0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        st *= 2.0;
    
        vec2 i_st = floor(st);
        vec2 f_st = fract(st);
        
        for(int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
            for(int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                vec2 neighbor = vec2(float(x),float(y));
                vec2 center = random2(i_st + neighbor);
                float radius = random(i_st + neighbor) * (1.0 / scale);
                vec2 diff = neighbor + center - f_st;
                
                float x = length(diff) / radius;
                float cavity = x * x - 1.0;
                float rimx = min(x - 1.0 - rimWidth, 0.0);
                float rim = rimSteepness * rimx * rimx;
                
                float craterShape = smoothMax(cavity, floorHeight, smoothness);
                craterShape = smoothMin(craterShape, rim, smoothness);

                height += craterShape * radius * amplitude;
            }
        }
        
        amplitude *= 0.6;
    }
    
    return height;
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;
    st *= 1.072;
    
    vec2 texel_size = 1.0 / u_resolution.xy;
    
    float offset = 0.0005;
    
    float height = cratersFractal(st);
    float hx = cratersFractal(st + vec2(offset, 0.0));
    float hy = cratersFractal(st + vec2(0.0, offset));
    vec2 dxy = height - vec2(hx, hy);
    
    vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(dxy * .1 / texel_size, 1.)) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    
    vec3 sun = normalize(vec3(0.8, 0.0, 0.0));

    float light = clamp(dot(normal, sun), 0.0, 1.0);
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(light),1.0);
}

Here's the result:

My problem lies in generating a normal map from the noise height data, I'm currently applying the central difference method explained in Inigo Quilze's article here.
Initially, I was calculating the normal map in another shader from the height map, but since I'm working on a surface cut with a quad tree, where each chunk uses a 256-by-256 texture, I quickly run into problems on the more detailed levels. The problem with the central difference method is that it requires me to calculate the height 4 times per texel (this normal map is generated on the fragment shader on 256 by 256 textures). I'd like to be able to use the analytic derivatives method, which is much more efficient in terms of calculation speed, but equally complex.
Has anyone done anything similar, or would anyone like to help me adapt the height map generation code for the analytic derivative method?

The trickiest bit is making versions of smoothMin and smoothMax that compute analytical derivatives.
I've hacked this version together based on Inigo Quilez's article on Smooth Minimums for SDFs, though my version could probably be better optimized.
It takes the usual parameters a, b, and k, plus the gradients of a and b, da and db, respectively. These are the vectors of partial derivatives with respect to our x and y sampling coordinates, so da = \$ \triangledown a = \left( \frac {\partial a} {\partial x}, \frac {\partial a} {\partial y} \right)\$. We then return the usual smooth minimum in the x component of a vector, and its gradient in the xy components:
vec3 smoothMin(float a, vec2 da, float b, vec2 db, float k) {
    k *= 4.0;
    float x = (b - a)/k;
    float h = (x + 1.0)/2.0;
    float dg = clamp(h, 0.0, 1.0);
    float g = h * dg + step(1, x) * (x - 1.0)/2.0;

    return vec3(mix(db, da, dg), b - k * g);
}

A similar strategy can be used to update smoothMax:
vec3 smoothMax(float a, vec2 da, float b, vec2 db, float k) {
    k *= 4.0;
    float x = (a - b)/k;
    float h = (x + 1.0)/2.0;
    float dg = clamp(h, 0.0, 1.0);
    float g = h * dg + step(1, x) * (x - 1.0)/2.0;

    return vec3(mix(db, da, dg), b + k * g);
}

Then we just need to compute these gradient vectors at each step, and carry them through all our operations. For each intermediate below that depends on our xy sample position, I've added a d version of the variable that holds its partial derivatives with respect to x and y.
float3 cratersFractal(vec2 st) {
    // Augment height with gradient vector in xy, and keep height in z:
    vec3 height = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    float amplitude = 1.0;

    // The rate that st changes relative to the original input.
    float scaleFactor = 1.0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        st *= 2.0;
        scaleFactor *= 2.0;
    
        vec2 i_st = floor(st);
        vec2 f_st = fract(st);
        
        for(int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
            for(int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                vec2 neighbor = vec2(float(x),float(y));
                vec2 center = random2(i_st + neighbor);
                float radius = random(i_st + neighbor) * (1.0 / scale);
                vec2 diff = neighbor + center - f_st;
                
                float x = length(diff) / radius;
                float2 dx = -scaleFactor * diff/(radius * length(diff));

                float cavity = x * x - 1.0;
                float2 dcavity = 2.0 * dx;

                float rimx = min(x - 1.0 - rimWidth, 0.0);
                float2 drimx = step(x, rimWidth + 1.0) * dx;

                float rim = rimSteepness * rimx * rimx;
                float drim = 2.0 * rimSteepness * drimx;
                
                vec3 craterShape = smoothMax(cavity, dcavity, floorHeight, (vec2)0.0, smoothness);

                craterShape = smoothMin(craterShape.z, cratershape.xy, rim, drim, smoothness);

                height += craterShape * radius * amplitude;                
            }
        }
        
        amplitude *= 0.6;
    }
    
    return height;
}

This returns the original height you'd computed in the z component, and the gradient in the xy components.
You can then compute the normal like so:
vec3 craters = cratersFractal(st);
float height = craters.z;

vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(-craters.xy, 1.0)) * 0.5 + 0.5;

You may need to scale the craters.xy gradient in that last step to adjust for the relative scale of your texture domain to height displacement.
It's still early AMs here, and I've only done a quick test of the smoothMin / smoothMax code, so I've probably made a math error somewhere in the derivation above, but hopefully that gives you a useful signpost to how to carry this through.

Thanks DMGrégorie for the explanations. It seems to me that the cratersFractal function body is good, I did some tests. There's just a problem with dSmoothMin and dSmoothMax with the variable dg which is a vec2, do you mean a float?
I'm sure it was at your place, I wrote my question around 11am local time in France ;)

Yep, fixed above.
